# Website on Smartphone changes height by keyboard

Tags: html, css, ios, web, smartphone

I dont know what to do anymore. When I visit my website on the
smartphone and start using forms, the page loses its height because the keyboard
opens. After closing the keyboard the page is still not full height.

I have already set the body and html height to 100vh / 100%.

This is what it looks like after closing the keyboard:

[image: example]

Comment: insert html and css

Comment: its a complete website, how should I insert it?